# llvm C++ APIのドキュメントについて

Tags: llvm

llvmのkaleidoScopeを試してみているのですが、その中で出てくるIRBuilderBaseクラスのメソッドが何をしているのかがよく分からなくなってきました。例えば、CreateFCmpULT(L, R, "cmptmp")がどういうメソッドなのかを調べても、公式のリファレンスでは依存関係が分かるだけでどういう風に使うのかの説明が有りませんでした。(解説してくださるサイトはありますが、勿論そのサイトも全てのメソッドについて解説しているわけではありません。)
https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilderBase.html
ここに載っているようなメソッドをどう使うかはどのように調べていますか？コードを読んで理解するというものなのでしょうか。